# ng-change isn't working on my semi-custom calendar control

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

For an app I'm working on, I may have coded myself into a corner.

Among the technologies we're using on this project, are Angular.js, and UI Bootstrap.  One of the first things I showed the team was the Calendar system in UI Bootstrap, and it was great!  Except...it was way too complex.  I was asked to build a simpler system.

I did just that.  However, I've hit a snag.

One of the things in our current application that we need to happen, is for our calendar system to raise `ng-change` events.  Given that the Calendar system is a non-standard tag that's merely wrapping an input field, I came up with the following code:

**Directive:**

```
(function() {
  angular.module('app').directive('calendar', [calendar]);

  function calendar() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: false,
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: 'calendar.html',
      controller: 'calendarCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'cal',
      compile: function(elem, attrs) {
        var inputName = attrs.inputName;
        var inputElement = elem.find('input');
        inputElement.attr('name', inputName);

        if (attrs.required)
          inputElement.attr('required', true);

        if (attrs.ngChange)
          inputElement.attr('ng-change', attrs.ngChange);

        // Compile returns a Link function!
        return function(scope, iElem, iAttrs, cal) {
          cal.boundProperty = attrs.ngModel;
          cal.bindFromProperty();
        };
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

[You can view the full plunker for this problem here](http://plnkr.co/edit/W99ojxlkoed2KmtBjbIK?p=preview)

...But, when I try to bind up a `ng-change` event...

**View:**

```
<body ng-controller="demoCtrl as vm">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      Hello, {{vm.user}}!
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Some Date:</label> 
      <calendar ng-model="vm.someDate" ng-change="vm.dateChanged()" input-name="someDate"></calendar>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

...Changing the calendar date simply yields no results.  (You should view a very noticeable message every time you tweak the calendar.)

**Question:** What exactly am I doing wrong, that's causing `ng-change` to not pick changes up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set ng-change that way. It has to be compiled by angular. Just set a ng-change on your input in your calendar template and have it call a function in your controller. That function will then call the ngChange expression (using "&", not $attrs) from your calendar directive's attribute.

http://plnkr.co/edit/RNQYcyq46bex0GPqDPRp

In your directive, remove the line that changes the input's ng-change attribute and add the '&' attribute to the isolate scope definition.

```
scope: {
    ngChange: '&'
},
```

In your calendar controller, add the ngChange call to the function you linked to your input's ng-change attribute:

```
function saveDateToBoundProperty() {
        $scope.ngChange();
        [...]
};
```

You should read about markup compilation ($compile and whatnot) and about directive isolate scopes (and @, =, and &).

Also, I would recommend not using ngChange as an attribute for a custom directive, since ngChange is itself a directive. It could lead to some unexpected behavior. you could use dateChange instead for instance.

Comment: Appreciate the additional info.  I didn't know what exactly to search on for @, =, and &.  I'll do more research.

Comment: google "angular directive isolate scope" for instance.